# Is there a way to sort 2 dataframes side by side in python and move those that are not in both to the bottom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am using python to automate some of the day to day in my work. I am looking for some assistance on how I might go about sorting 2 dataframes side by side and moving those values that are not in both to the bottom of the dataframe in which is originated.

For example in the two dataframes below once it gets to WWT0117 (left hand df) there is a small residual amount of 0.03. WWT0117 is not in the dataframe on the right so I want to move this WWT0117 and the corresponding 0.03 value to the bottom of the dataframe.

The below is a view of the two dataframes side by side and the highlighted is where is goes a skew. The dataframes are a lot bigger and is tedious to go through line by line.

[image]

Comment: `(df1.column_name + df2.column_name).abs().sort_values()` will sort the absolute value of the sum in ascending order. You'll have to clarify the question to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this answer doesn't correspond to what you wanted, please clarify what you want. As it stands, there is some room for interpretation of your question.

### First method: join by names

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name1':['WWT0034', 'WWT0039', 'WWT0117', 'WWT0119'], 'v1':[-80832.72, 3949.78,0.03,-0.05]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2':['WWT0034', 'WWT0039', 'WWT0140', 'WWT0180'], 'v2':[80832.72, -3949.78,344.46,83464.11]})
# df1                      df2
#      name1        v1          name2        v2
# 0  WWT0034 -80832.72     0  WWT0034  80832.72
# 1  WWT0039   3949.78     1  WWT0039  -3949.78
# 2  WWT0117      0.03     2  WWT0140    344.46
# 3  WWT0119     -0.05     3  WWT0180  83464.11

df = df1.set_index('name1').join(df2.set_index('name2'), how='outer')
# df
#                v1        v2
# WWT0034 -80832.72  80832.72
# WWT0039   3949.78  -3949.78
# WWT0117      0.03       NaN
# WWT0119     -0.05       NaN
# WWT0140       NaN    344.46
# WWT0180       NaN  83464.11

(df['v1'] + df['v2']) == 0
# WWT0034     True
# WWT0039     True
# WWT0117    False
# WWT0119    False
# WWT0140    False
# WWT0180    False

df[(df['v1'] + df['v2']) == 0]
#                v1        v2
# WWT0034 -80832.72  80832.72
# WWT0039   3949.78  -3949.78
```

### Second method: join by row number after sorting

Or alternatively:

```py
>>> df = df1.sort_values(by='name1').reset_index(drop=True).join(df2.sort_values(by='name2').reset_index(drop=True))

>>> df
     name1        v1    name2        v2
0  WWT0034 -80832.72  WWT0034  80832.72
1  WWT0039   3949.78  WWT0039  -3949.78
2  WWT0117      0.03  WWT0140    344.46
3  WWT0119     -0.05  WWT0180  83464.11

>>> df[(df['v1'] + df['v2']) == 0]
     name1        v1    name2        v2
0  WWT0034 -80832.72  WWT0034  80832.72
1  WWT0039   3949.78  WWT0039  -3949.78

>>> df[(df['v1'] + df['v2']) != 0]
     name1    v1    name2        v2
2  WWT0117  0.03  WWT0140    344.46
3  WWT0119 -0.05  WWT0180  83464.11
```

### Difference between the two methods

Note that those two methods **are not** equivalent. The first method joins the two dataframes based on the `'name1'` and `'name2'` columns; the second method ignores the names and joins them based on the row numbers after sorting.

Here is an example of two dataframes that would give different results with the two different methods:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name1':['WWT0034', 'WWT0039', 'WWT0117', 'WWT0119', 'WWT0120'], 'v1':[-80832.72, 3949.78,0.03,-0.05, 42]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2':['WWT0034', 'WWT0039', 'WWT0118', 'WWT0120', 'WWT0180'], 'v2':[80832.72, -3949.78,344.46,-42, 83464.11]})
# df1                      df2
#      name1        v1          name2        v2
# 0  WWT0034 -80832.72     0  WWT0034  80832.72
# 1  WWT0039   3949.78     1  WWT0039  -3949.78
# 2  WWT0117      0.03     2  WWT0118    344.46
# 3  WWT0119     -0.05     3  WWT0120    -42.00
# 4  WWT0120     42.00     4  WWT0180  83464.11
```

The first method would join the two `'WWT0120'` together, whereas the second method would keep them separate.